# Mercedes ML320 fuel pump stops after 3-4 seconds

Tags: mercedes-benz, fuel-pump, ml320

The fuel pump in my 98 Mercedes ML 320 died last summer. I replaced it then, but now it's having issues.  When I turn the key slowly, I can hear the pump kick in, but when the starter kicks in it shuts back off.  The engine will start for 4-5 seconds, then stop.  I've put my multimeter on the electrical lines, and it reads 5v on the gauge lines and 12 volts on the power lines... but only for those same 4-5 seconds.  I've checked the relay and fuse and both look good.

Where else can I look?

Comment: Not sure about the MB, but most vehicles will run the fuel pump for a few seconds KOEO, then stop powering it until you actually start the vehicle. You're saying, even after you start the vehicle, the pump only gets power for the 4-5 seconds? Have you put a fuel pressure gauge at the fuel rail to see what the actual reading is when you start it?

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 "KOEO"? What does that mean? And I'll check the pressure on the rail.

Comment: KOEO = Key On; Engine Off